# Macro to execute only if range of cells all contain the word "OK"

Tags: validation, excel, excel-2007, vba

As the title states, I need a macro that can only be executed if a range of cells all contain the word "OK". This is based off of a formula, that checks that certain criteria are met before I can push an order through to another sheet in the same workbook. I have a Macro for that already, all I need is to setup the criteria validation that will check the cell range, make sure all cells within range say "OK", run the Macro if it checks out, otherwise, prompt a message box saying the Order is not correct as entered.

Comment: What program? It sounds like you're talking about Excel, but you need to specify that.

Comment: What language or program? This needs to specify it and tag for it.

Comment: Ooops, my mistake. It is for excel. Adding tags, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In two steps might be simplest:

1. If a contiguous range, say E5:J5 where Row5 is the relevant one, add `=COUNTIF(E5:J5,"OK")` somewhere in your worksheet, say K5 (adjust formula to suit), then
2. in your macro, test the value in K5 and if not =6 exit with your error message, else proceed to your 'push order' macro.